# Extra datetime information IE

Tags: python, django, internet-explorer, datetime

I've got a Django site, and on one of the pages it displays the server's current time.  This works fine on most browsers, but for some reason I see extra, redundant information in IE.

For example, in Chrome/FF/Safari it might say:

```
"Tue Sep 18 2014 02:34:56 PM EDT [UTC-0400]"
```

but in IE, it says

```
"Tue Sep 18 2014 14:3 02:34:56 PM EDT [UTC-0400]"
```

It prints the current hour (in 24 hr mode) and the first character of the minutes before going on to print the rest of the string.

Python:

```
def view_page(request):
    infoDict = {}
    #set some other infoDict key:value pairs
    cur_time = now.strftime("%a, %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p")
    server_timezone = now.strftime("%Z [UTZ%z]")
    infoDict['server_time'] = cur_time + " " + server_timezone
    #do some more stuff
    return renderutils.render_response(infoDict)
```

HTML:

```
<b><span id="current_time">{{server_time}}</span></b>
```

Anybody know why this would be different on IE than other browsers??

Comment: Did you try using an explicit date formatting tag? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: No, but the string is built in python and then passed to HTML, so I'm not sure why it should matter what tag I'm using.